# Spreadsheet::WriteExcel not writing string in Excel using merge_range

Tags: perl

I am using `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel` to create an excel and write some data into it.
I am using the `merge_range` to merger some cells.
But the problem is my below code does merge cells but dont show the data in it (`$str` contents).
I am not able to figure out why????.

Please help me, where did i going wrong?

Below is the part of my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
use strict;

my $wb = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('excel_test.xls');
my $custom_ws = $wb->add_worksheet('Custom Parameters');

my $wb_format_merge = $wb->add_format();
$wb_format_merge->set_bold();
$wb_format_merge->set_text_wrap();
$wb_format_merge->set_border(1);
$wb_format_merge->set_align('left');
$wb_format_merge->set_valign('vcenter');

my($row, $coll) = 0;
my $merge_coll_len = 8;

###### write data ###
my $str = "Please select the follwong metrics to generate custom report in Details sheet";
$custom_ws->merge_range($row, $coll, $row, $coll + $merge_coll_len, $str,$merge_format);

$row += 2;
$custom_ws->write($row, $coll, 'select the data type for the reference');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my($row, $coll) = 0;
```

`$coll` is undefined

use

`my($row, $coll)=(0,0);`

Using 4 row,coll,row,coll for the `merge_range` is perfectly valid (provided they have values ;)  )

Comment: ++ Correct answer. @kailash19 Adding "use warnings" to the program would have caught this.

Comment: Was so silly to point it out :P that time.. also havenot accepted the answer, so accepting it :)

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see in the [`Spreadsheet::WriteExcel`](https://metacpan.org/module/Spreadsheet%3a%3aWriteExcel) documentation example, the cell ranges are supposed to be passed as a single string argument, although as John points out, separate arguments are valid also:

For the single argument form, it would look like this:

```
$custom_ws->merge_range('A1:H1', $str, $merge_format);
```

One idea could be to roll a couple of helper subroutines to allow for the use of this form:

```
sub range {

   my ( $from_row, $from_col ) = @{ $_[0] };
   my ( $to_row, $to_col ) = @{ $_[1] };

   die "Expecting to go from top-left to bottom-right"
       if $from_row > $to_row || $from_col > $to_col;

   return join '', alpha( $from_row ), $from_col, ':', alpha( $to_row ), $to_col;
}

sub alpha {
    my $row = 'A';
    $row++ for 1 .. +shift;
    return $row;
}
```

And then call `range`:

```
$custom_ws->merge_range( range( [ $row, $col ],
                                [ $row, $col + $length ] ),
                         $str,
                         $merge_format );
```

Comment: The merge_range() method works with either $row, $col style parameters or an A1 style range string. Also, there are functions to convert between each type in the Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::Utility module.

Comment: @jmcnamara : Serves me right for not paying closer attention to the documentation